# read array and display html div

Tags: javascript, html

how do I display my array "employee" to this table?

the idea is to display each name with on button on the side.

```
<div id="projectPopUp" class="popup-window" style="display:none">
  <div class="popuptitle" id="details-name"></div>
  <table width="100%" id="detailsgrid">
    <tr>
      <tr class="bb cls-{id} active-{active}">
        <td class="active-{active}" id="{id}-list" width="70%">{employees}</td>
        <td class="cls-{id} active-{active}" width="30%">
          <button class="buttons" step="0.01" 
                  data-clear-btn="false" 
                  style="background: #006b54; color:white !important ;" 
                  id="{id}-inspectSelected">
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <button class="smallButton" onClick="closePopup()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var employees = ['usera', 'userb', 'userc'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check out these lessons by W3 Schools:

**Creating elements:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

**Changing Inner Html:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp